# Algolia filtering compare two strings with greater or less than

Tags: javascript, ascii, algolia

I am using Algolia for a web application using the JS SDK and I am trying to filter by
a string value using comparison operators like >, <, >=, etc...

I was expecting it to be filtering the strings by ASCII value like "ac" < "ba"

I tried solving this by using the following code:

```
return index.search(query, {
   filters: "myId <= 'ba'"
});
```

Expecting it to return only records with IDs like 'acd', 'ax', 'ba', ...

But I got the error:
`filters: Unexpected token string(ba) expected numeric at col 13`

My question is now: Is this even supported by Algolia or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: afaik what you are trying works for [numericFilters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/numericFilters/)

Comment: @cmgchess I tried using numericFilters: ["myId > 'Ac'"] but unfortunately it doesn't work either. I get the error: Invalid syntax for numeric condition:myId > "A"

Comment: yeah unfortunately it works only for number fields